# If I save a frequently updated YouTube playlist, are the updated videos automatically saved in your Library?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Let's say today I save a YouTube playlist from another channel with 154 videos, and it has 1 new video updated to it everyday. If I go to my Library and click this playlist tomorrow, does it have 154 videos or 155 videos?

Comment: If you save someone else's playlist that playlist continues to be managed by the owner.  If you have saved a frequently updated playlist you can easily confirm this yourself.  Are you encountering a problem you need help with?